# How we get dual sim number from the device in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to know user mobile number in Android. I am using mobile_number package to get dual sim number from the device in android. However, using this package I am getting only sim 1 number.

I used this code but I am not getting number.

```
@override void initState() { MobileNumber.listenPhonePermission((isPermissionGranted) { if (isPermissionGranted) { initMobileNumberState(); } else {} }); initMobileNumberState();
super.initState();}

Future<void> initMobileNumberState() async { if (!await MobileNumber.hasPhonePermission) { await MobileNumber.requestPhonePermission; return; } try { // String  _mobileNumber = (await MobileNumber.mobileNumber)!; // toastMessage(text: "Mobile : $_mobileNumber"); List<SimCard>? simCards = await MobileNumber.getSimCards; for (SimCard simCard in simCards!) { print("Carrier: ${simCard.carrierName}"); print("Country: ${simCard.countryIso}"); print("Number: ${simCard.number}"); } } on PlatformException catch (e) {
}

// If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
// message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
// setState to update our non-existent appearance.
if (!mounted) return;

setState(() {});
}
```

I am expecting both sim number from the device.

Comment: Try simply reading the documentation of the package at https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_number . It shows `Get List of sim cards for dual sim cards
`